# How to Move through Application's Screens

Tags: javafx

How to implement a callback interface to go for example from Main Menu screen to start period screen when pressing start period button and return to Main menu screen when pressing main menu button in start period screen.

[Main Menu screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylSmT.png)
[Start period screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xebit.png)

Comment: BTW: "stages" is misleading here. The reader may think you mean [`javafx.stage.Stage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html)s

Comment: I apologize for interrupting like this!, I already edit it. Now My question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataFX](http://www.javafxdata.org/) and its Flow mechanism. If you prefer not to use an external library you can do one of the following:

1. Use a single controller for UI, have a reference to all your UI "screens" which are essentially some type of containers, like BorderPane, VBox, etc. When button start is clicked, you change the root of the `Scene` to period UI. Having same controller class means all references are in the same place, so when go back button is pressed, you change the root back to main UI.
2. If your code is rather big, you can use controllers for each UI, but then you will need to implement some basic global event system. When a change in the `Scene`'s root is required you fire an event, say `CHANGE_SCENE`, and attach some info, like the reference to the UI root. Once the event is caught, change the `Scene` root to the one you received by the event system.